# Sql insert as a "insert block" method

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

I need to insert data from Oracle to MySQL.

Like this. (For example query with two records (In real 500))

```
INSERT INTO test_table
            (bill_balance, 
             prime_uid, 
             customer_id, 
             account_name, 
             phone, 
             street, 
             bill_dt, 
             account_no) 
VALUES      ('111', 
             '123456', 
             '1234-56789', 
             'My name is', 
             '20373359', 
             'Street name', 
             '1970-01-01 02:00:00', 
             '123456'), 
            ('2', 
             '123', 
             '123-123', 
             'TEST', 
             '', 
             'test 123', 
             '1970-01-01 02:00:00', 
             '123456789')
```

I had this error:**MySQL server has gone away**.
In php I have made those settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set("memory_limit", "512M"); 
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
set_time_limit(0);

ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('interactive_timeout', 3600);
ini_set('wait_timeout', 3600);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 60);
ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent', true);
```

it works, with simple "insert",  It's not working with block insert method.

Comment: This is your complete INSERT, two records? Or is the actual command causing the error bigger?

Comment: "Like this" indicates that its just a representation of the structure ;) To timeout he would need alot more records.

Comment: No it's not a complete INSERT.500 records in one insert.I'm trying to do it with two records..and it's did't work too.

Comment: Are you doing this query regularly, or just once?

Comment: Regularly = 1 million /(500 inserts in one block) = 2000 times

Answer (score 2):

You probably exceeded the allowed packet size.
Compare the result of `strlen($yourQuery)`(+ some feasible margin) to the result of
`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`

see also:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet